# Pandas apply function when database is the 2nd positional argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

Lets say I have a function

```
def fun(x, y):
    return(y.sum() + x)
```

This function takes in a value to add **x**, and a database/series to sum **y**

If I have a database **df**, that I would like to apply my function to. However, the data base is meant to be the second positional argument not the first.

```
df.apply(fun, x = 10)
```

returns an error **"("fun() got multiple values for argument 'x'", 'occurred at index 0')**

How do I use the apply function so that the database is the **second** positional argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not allowed to modify function `fun`, you need additional lambda inside `apply` as follows:

```
df.apply(lambda col: fun(10, col))
```